# Terraform persistent and dynamic infrastructure parts?

Tags: terraform

I want to divide my infrastructure into two parts:

1. Persistent (firewalls, block storages, etc)
2. Dynamic (that will consume persistent resources from #1)

I want to be sure that persistent part never would be deleted and at the same time, there would be an option `terraform destroy` on the dynamic infrastructure part.

Comment: I was just looking into this and did not find any useful info. Apparently terraform has no concept of persistent infrastructure (call it static?), so I created a feature request (link below) with a possible implementation idea for such where a resource could be marked as persistent and kept upon a terraform destroy execution. You might want to have keep an eye on https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20065.

Answer (score 0):

All resources you do not want to destroy you have to add the lifecycle policy: prevent_destroy

Have a look at the documenation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#prevent_destroy

Comment: Yeah, but `prevent_destroy` just preventing `destroy` command if a resource with this directive is planned for deletion. And I want to be able to destroy "dynamic" part of the infrastructure and leave "persistent".

Answer (score 0):

To fully prevent the destruction you would have to fine tune the permissions on the resources at your provider. However there is an easy way to divide your infrastructure.

Terraform offers a [remote state data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) which allows you to use output from a different project so you won't be able to destroy those resources while working with the dynamic part.

Comment: Can you provide an example how to solve an issue from the question? As I get it remote state allows to use `.tfstate` that is more like version control for one project then importing output from another project.

Comment: @AlexT Well, you create one project for the persistent infrastracture and another for dynamic infrastracture. You only work on the dynamic project, refer to the outputs from the other project thru the remote state provider and so you can't accidentally delete anything and you can prevent some users from modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a different work around. The resources I do not want to delete with "terraform destroy" I create as "null_resource" using a provisioner with CLI. You can still use your variables in terraform as well.

for example (Create a resource group, but it is persistent due to null_resource)

```
resource "null_resource" "backend-config" {
        provisioner "local-exec" {
        command     = <<EOT
    az group create --location ${var.Location} --name ${var.Resource_group_name} --tags 'LineOfBusiness=${var.Lob}' 'Region=${var.Region}' 'Purpose="Terraform-Primary-Resource-Group-${var.Lob}'
    EOT
        interpreter = ["Powershell", "-Command"]
      }
    }
```

Now if you destroy the resources using terraform destroy. Any null_resource will remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by having 2 Terraform deployments. You create the "static" resources once, and don't touch them. For extra safety, manually add a deletion lock to those resources (eg. I know you can do this in Azure, I assume other cloud providers have a similar solution).

Import these resources in your Dynamic Terraform deployment, using **data** blocks (not resources). Terraform will never attempt to delete resources you import using data blocks.